# couldn't run hadoop on docker swarm in vagrant

Tags: docker, hadoop, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have 4 vagrant machines running and source code for vagrant environment is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/swarm/blob/master/Vagrantfile).

I'm successfully able to create a swarm cluster.

```
            [vagrant@master ~]$ docker service ls
    ID                  NAME                     MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                                    PORTS
    4j5742f3lxsm        hadoop_datanode          global              0/6                 bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.2-java8          
    xji061560z88        hadoop_historyserver     replicated          0/1                 bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.2-java8     
    0kbyu97c0k7i        hadoop_namenode          replicated          0/1                 bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.2-java8          
    z81o9vj3btxt        hadoop_nodemanager       global              0/6                 bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.2-java8       
    dj5m6b6rlsel        hadoop_resourcemanager   replicated          0/1                 bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.2-java8
```

Then I tried to deploy the [hadoop](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop) on this swarm cluster `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose-v3.yml hadoop`

```
           [vagrant@master docker-hadoop-master]$ docker node ls                     
    ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
    2gxw29laf7eny3ulbtgqv4u8s     datanode            Ready               Active                                  19.03.3
    d16n9gesifbm3v6n4mva9sc48     historyserver       Ready               Active                                  19.03.3
    ald04wst5ct2ewybrt1y5cl2d *   master.com          Ready               Active              Leader              19.03.3
    oxo5hmcq9cqhv36ci6s0y2kwp     namenode            Ready               Active                                  19.03.3
    9ugmvy2bj8d67ue5w6nt7bf21     nodemanager1        Ready               Active                                  19.03.3
    9o4lmysp17jo2efyxlvbhwknr     resourcemanager     Ready               Active                                  19.03.3
```

Also, I tried to get logs for namenode but it has no logs

```
    $ docker service logs hadoop_namenode
```

Now I don't get  logs for any of the any of the services.

The respective ip and hostname of docker nodes are [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/swarm/blob/master/Vagrantfile#L5-L36).
How can I fix this issue and make the hadoop cluster run vagrant swarm cluster?

Comment: Can try setting a hostname in your docker-compose.yml for the namenode / datanode then down / up the containers?

Comment: For the first error, None of the nodes are called `namenode`

Comment: I changed the VM names and updated the question. Now I don't see any logs for any of the services. Any idea?